# Do Java compilers commonly precompute hashcodes of final fields?

Tags: java, optimization, compiler-construction

I have a `HashMap`-intensive Java program in which several classes have hashcodes computed from `final` fields. For example:

```
public class Foo {
    private final int bar;
    private final String zot;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + bar;
        result = prime * result + zot.hashCode();
        return result;
    }
}
```

It's possible for the compiler to observe that the hashcode cannot change after object initialization, and precompute it into an additional `private final` field. Do current Java compilers do this, like the one in Oracle JDK 7? I could disassmble the `.class` file, but then the JIT may also do this kind of optimization at runtime and I would not see it there. Anyway, I'm interested in other cases besides this one, so it would be great to find a general approach for identifying any optimizations the compiler does automatically.

Comment: If the objects never actually get used in a `HashMap` or anything else that invokes their `hashCode` method, then what you are describing is an anti-optimization.

Comment: A compiler can't do this, but there's an [ongoing discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/project-lombok/ImSQ7X7PeBo/CzvK72Bqk9kJ) about introducing it in Lombok

Comment: @LouisWasserman: it's very common for a JIT to profile the app for hot methods and start moving them around. For example, any method that exclusively accesses static and private fields is a candidate for being inlined into any frequent caller. This is an expensive optimization, so it only happens for methods that are observed to be hot. But what I want to know is, how can we find out what optimizations the JIT is making? It would be great to have a doc, or some way to introspect it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do current Java compilers do this, like the one in Oracle JDK 7?

The `javac` does almost no optimisations.

> I could disassmble the .class file,

You might not like what you see in terms of optimisations. ;)

> but then the JIT may also do this kind of optimization at runtime and I would not see it there.

If the JIT did optimise this, you wouldn't see it and in fact it doesn't do this.  This is why String caches it's hashCode() at runtime, explicitly in code.

Comment: Cool, thanks. But how do you know? It would be nice to have a resource for the next time I have this kind of question.

Comment: @ByronHawkins I know something about the header and the data storage area.  There is no room for caching a user generated hashCode and String has to do it explicitly which is would not do if the JIT did it for you.

Comment: @ByronHawkins: Wasting an extra four bytes per object could be detrimental to programs that allocate a ton of these objects.  So it's not really a safe, or sane, thing for the JVM to do.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: True, but if you change the object in such a way while it's sitting in a HashMap, you're playing with fire.  The kind of fire that wants to burn and disfigure you horribly.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I'm not sure I understand about the class header. Both the compiler and the JIT are able to add fields, just as if the developer had put them in the class directly. This is a benefit of Java over languages with visible pointers like C/C++, where the compiler can't add fields or change memory layout. How can we know the JIT will not move the `hashCode()` computation into the constructor if its profiler shows that method to be hot?

Comment: @ByronHawkins I am not saying it couldn't.  I am saying it doesn't on any platform I know of.  Given OpenJDK is the reference implementation and it doesn't, I suspect caching the hashCode automagically is performing work which is too expensive if not needed and too easy to break. e.g. if you have setter methods which many classes do.

Answer (score 2):

No, compilers do not do this. However, it wouldn't be hard to store the hash code yourself in a field, and refer to that instead of computing anew all the time:

```
private int hash = -1;

public int hashCode() {
    if (hash == -1) {
        // compute hash, assign it to the hash variable, and return it
    } else {
        return hash;
    }
}
```

This approach is actually taken by the `String` class, which you can see if you inspect its [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java):

```
121  /** Cache the hash code for the string */
122  private int hash; // Default to 0
```

Comment: Thanks--but how do you know? It would be nice to have a resource for the next time I have this kind of question.

Comment: @ByronHawkins You can view the bytecode with `javap`, as another answer suggested.

Comment: @zhong.j.yu This should be perfectly fine. Please elaborate.

Comment: @zhong.j.yu It isn't synchronized or locked, but it's thread-safe. The implementation in `java.lang.String` isn't synchronized or locked either, which proves the point. The only harm is that the same `hash` value might get computed more than once occasionally, which isn't worth locking against.

Comment: see http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/12/benign-data-races-in-java.html (scroll down to "Now, let's break the code"

Comment: @zhong.j.yu I can't agree with the author that 'the second read can actually be moved ... before the first'.

Comment: @EJP: The Java memory model is too weak to allow you to write all kinds of sensible-looking code.  (See Locking, double-checked.)  Reads to non-volatile variables within the same thread aren't sequenced with respect to one another unless there's a write in between.  And that's exactly what you have here, counterintuitive as it may appear.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible for the compiler to do that for any suitable method, not just `hashCode(),` but it doesn't. You can see for yourself via `javap -p` whether there are any added fields, and you can also see the bytecode with `javap -c`.

However the method you have posted isn't a suitable candidate. The implementation of `String.hashCode()` at runtime could be different from the one available to the compiler. The compiler can't assume it isn't.

Comment: +1 I didn't think of the point you raised in your second paragraph.

Comment: The optimization can be done--the compiler just moves the `hashCode()` computation into the constructor(s), so it gets computed at runtime with correct values. It's very common for a JIT to inline hot methods, so if it sees excessive calls to an obviously static method like this `hashCode()`, it's certainly possible for the JIT to rebuild the class. Still looking for a way to find out which of these optimizations are actually done in practice.